# Find matrix of a given linear transformation in given new bases

Tags: linear-algebra

2. Find matrix of a given linear transformation L->M in given new bases:

a) $L =< e_1,e_2,e_3 >, M =< g_1,g_2 >, f(e_1) = g_1 − 2g_2, f(e_2) = g_1 + g_2, f(e_3) = 2g_1 + 3g_2,
$
$
\bar e_1 = 2e_1 − e_3, \bar e_2 = e_2 + e_3,  \bar e_3 = e_1 − e_2, \bar g_1 = g_1 + 2g_2, \bar g_2 = 2g_1 − g_2
$$

I know similar questions have been asked but they didn't help me because I am unsure if my data matches the data in the other answers. Please note there is a difference between $e_1$ and $\bar e_1 $.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the solution to this question, how would you attack it? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I have no clue whatsoever. If you could tell me what data is what then I could think of something, ie what are the bases and such.

Comment: Do you know how to write the matrix representing $f$ with respect to the bases $L$ and $M$?

Comment: yes, I know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find $a_{ij}$ such that

$$ f(\overline{e}_1) = a_{11} \overline{g}_1 + a_{21} \overline{g}_2, \\ 
   f(\overline{e}_2) = a_{12} \overline{g}_1 + a_{22} \overline{g}_2, \\
   f(\overline{e}_3) = a_{13} \overline{g}_1 + a_{23} \overline{g}_2. $$

You have

$$ f(\overline{e}_1) = f(2e_1 - e_3) = 2f(e_1) - f(e_3) = 2(g_1 - 2g_2) - (2g_1 + 3g_2) =  -7g_2, \\
f(\overline{e}_2) = f(e_2 + e_3) = f(e_2) + f(e_3) = (g_1 + g_2) + (2g_1 + 3g_2) = 3g_1 + 4g_2, \\
f(\overline{e}_3) = f(e_1 - e_2) = f(e_1) - f(e_2) = (g_1 - 2g_2) - (g_1 + g_2) = -3g_2. $$

You will finish if you find out how to express $g_i$ in terms of $\overline{g}_1, \overline{g}_2$ which I'll leave to you.